# Karpenter node/machine creation metrics not present on karpenter.karpenter.svc.cluster.local:8000/metrics on scaling up

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, metrics, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, karpenter

I am using karpenter to handle autoscaling in my EKS cluster. As per the karpenter [metrics doc](https://karpenter.sh/preview/concepts/metrics/) karpenter exposes its metrics on karpenter.karpenter.svc.cluster.local:8000/metrics . I could see the metrics on this port. Expected behavior is that when the karpenter scales up and adds new Nodes/machine to the EKS cluster below metrics must be present -

1. karpenter_machines_created
2. karpenter_nodes_created
   Similarly on termination when Karpenter scales down we should see below metrics -
3. karpenter_nodes_terminated
4. karpenter_machines_terminated

Unfortunately I am not able to see these metrics.What is wrong in this any help ??

I am able to successfully collect the metrics on karpenter.karpenter.svc.cluster.local:8000/metrics
But I am not able to see below metrics on scaling up -

1. karpenter_machines_created
2. karpenter_nodes_created

And below metrics on scaling down -

1. karpenter_nodes_terminated
2. karpenter_machines_terminated